# "Move Discussion to Chat" and 1 rep users

Tags: feature-request, chat, reputation

I would be happy to move a certain comment discussion with a new member to chat as suggested by the auto message—but that question asker has one 1 rep.  She wouldn't even be able to comment except that it is her own question.

## Feature request

Either:

- Don't show the "move to chat" suggestion one of the participants has insufficient reputation.
- Drop the rep requirement for chat rooms, but give highly privileged users (say 10K or higher) in small sites the ability to "kick out" spammers or offenders who have not earned reputation.   Not sure what the business rules would be here, but it is probably worth a discussion in the design team.
- Preferably:  create a special chat room, and given that new user permissions only for that 
  chat.  In other words, a new user can enter a chat room *only when created for them by a reputable user*, and they are therefore directly invited.

It doesn't help to tell me that I shouldn't engage in a long discussion, when there is no other way to communicate with the new user :-)

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't do the third one already? I believe "move to chat" already creates a new room for the chat.

Comment: Yeah, cause I tried it with this particular user.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. Meta discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep

Comment: Just FYI, I asked Shog9 about rep requirements at one point (in The Frying Pan, of course), and most rep requirements are site-specific, but chat ones are network-wide. But I agree, it'd be nice if the question-specific chats were exempted. At least for the participants in the comments.

Comment: I came here tonight to ask/say the same thing. It bugs the hell out of me.